# How do I remove the message bar saying "For quick access, place your bookmarks..."

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

At the top of my Chromium (Ubuntu) window, there is a bar saying "For quick access, place your bookmarks here on the bookmarks bar. Import bookmarks now..."

I do not want a bookmarks bar at all. How do I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 5):

There is unfortunately no way to get rid of the bar unless you import your bookmarks.  It will always appear on the new tab page, but if you press CTRL+Shift+B it will get rid of it on every other tab, as the checks/unchecks the "Always show bookmarks bar" button in settings.

Sources: Hours of scouring Google Forums and personal experience

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/M3sK9CJqVZ8
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BpRQ75q4AWk

(I had 8 more links but I don't have enough rep to add them)

Comment: CTRL+Shift+B actually works on Firefox to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately unchecking View->Show bookmarks bar does not help. Instead open Menu->Settings->Appearance and uncheck "Always show the bookmarks bar".

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The next day the annoying message bar came back.

Comment: This one is working for me.

Comment: Doesn't work. They are the same functionality. If you open a new tab, the message will still be there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Blank new tab page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page) extension...works perfect.

Comment: Would you try to be more specific?

Comment: What Kmarsh is trying to say is that .. once you hide the bookmarks bar by >>open Menu->Settings->Appearance and uncheck "Always show the bookmarks bar". it WILL still show up only on new tab pages, since they are google new tab pages.. but if you dont want to see that message on any page .. dload the extension called blank new tab page . clear?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite annoying. That message is part of Chromium's "New Tab" page (which looks like google.com, but it's not). The New Tab page your bookmarks as part of the webpage, even if you uncheck Show Bookmarks. And if you don't have any bookmarks, then it will show the "For quick access, place your bookmarks here on the bookmarks bar" message instead.

The workarounds are:

1. Add a bookmark. You can uncheck Show Bookmarks so the bookmarks bar doesn't show on most pages. But it will still be rendered on the New Tab page
2. You cannot change Chromium's New Tab page, unless you install a plugin that lets you override it. I like [New Tab Url by Stephen Blott](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-url/njigpponciklokfkoddampoienefegcl?hl=en) because it is super simple and lighweight, without fancy extra features. You can then set the New Tab page to open to e.g. https://google.com.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the Toolbar -> Hover over "*Bookmarks Toolbar*" -> Click "*Never*".

[image]